# SSH and Latent Connections (e.g., satellite connections)

Tags: ssh, latency

Most of the week I live in the city where I have a typical broadband connection, but most weekends I'm out of town and only have access to a satellite connection. Trying to work over SSH on a satellite connection, while possible, is hardly desirable due to the high latency (> 1 second).

**My question is this:**
Is there any software that will do something like buffering keystrokes on my local machine before they're sent over SSH to help make the lag on individual keystrokes a little bit more transparent? Essentially I'm looking for something that would reduce the effects of the high latency for everything except for commands (e.g., opening files, changing to a new directory, etc.).

I've already discovered that vim can open remote files locally and rewrite them remotely, but, while this is a huge help, it is not quite what I'm looking for since it only works when editing files, and requires opening a connection every time a read/write occurs. 
(*For anyone who may not know how to do this and is curious, just use this command: 'vim scp://host/file/path/here)*

Comment: +1 good question. Also useful when doing work remotely on a client's system which is only hooked up via modem (we have that a lot :-( ).

Comment: Nagle's algorithm from [RFC 896](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc896) should do what you want; buffer the keystrokes and send one big packet instead of multiple smaller packets.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount and browse around the remote filesystem with a local shell. You won't have latency while typing commands, but only when listing the contents of directories and accessing files. This includes significant delay on tab completion, since this triggers a listing of the current directory's contents.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really old but, for posterity, [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) is a wonderful solution to this problem.

My only problem with it is that as of now it doesn't support [SSH agent forwarding](https://github.com/keithw/mosh/issues/120). The workaround I use is to have a separate SSH connection open, which I use when I need to git push to private repositories, establish tunnels, etc.